# How to get redirect url with query string using CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, drupal, single-sign-on

Currently i am doing Single Sign on Project with drupal.

When i click on this url

```
http://example.com/api/login
```

in return it will redirect me to

```
http://example1.com/success.php?response=qawsedrftgQAWSSS
```

Now I am sending a CURL request to same url

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch)

preg_match_all('/^Location:(.*)$/mi', $response, $matches);
$redirect = !empty($matches[1]) ? trim($matches[1][0]) : null;
```

$redirect gives me

```
http://example1.com/success.php
```

But i want

```
http://example1.com/success.php?response=qawsedrftgQAWSSS
```

Can any one help me please..

Thanks in advance.